# Latest versions of PHP and Swiftmailer lead to an attached file sent through as "ATT00001.bin" - why is that?

Tags: php, html, swiftmailer

This is my first question so please go easy with me - and I'll try to be as concise / accurate as possible.

I've been using PHP and Swiftmailer for 5+ years now, so that's why this new install situation is throwing me. It's a brand new Windows Server 2019 setup, and I'm using PHP version [7.3](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.3) which is as close to current as it gets.

After setting up [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer), regular emails are flowing through normally, however any attachment file doesn't get attached in the regular fashion and the only thing sent is a "*ATT00001.bin*" file - which is simply the filename of the attachment.

I tried testing a more simple attachment program, stripping the program down to its bare core, and I'm still stuck either way. I also read that the attachment file **must** be the last thing added after the message - which is the case here since the variable is entirely set beforehand. This is so odd since as mentioned I've been using this setup for a long time and it's a simple scenario.

Here are some coding excerpts for reference, and you'll notice that it's an HTML email - which is all contained in the "*email_message*" variable and 
it's defined **before** the attachment is added to the "*message*" instance:

```
<?php

// ~ ~ Set contents into Body portion of the email. ~ ~ //
$message->setBody($email_message, 'text/html');

// ~ ~ Set the attachment file location for inclusion. ~ ~ //
$target_path = "d:/directory_name/email/attachments/test_file.pdf";

// ~ ~ Add on the file using a dynamic path. ~ ~ //
$message->attach(new Swift_Attachment($target_path));

?>
```

The MS exchange server setup is the same, and everything is still working with the old version of SwiftMailer (5.0.0) on the old server.

At this point I'm ready to go back to the old version of Swiftmailer to at least get the attachments sending through again. :\

Please help me if possible, and if more details are needed then I will update this post.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: So the problem is not the latest PHP version but the newer version of SwiftMailer, right ? Have you checked the antivirus software is not interfering? If it works with the old version of SwiftMailer - I would use it instead of the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and I'd LOVE to stay with the old working version - however my manager has pushed to use the newest version either way. As far as virus programs,  Sophos will be installed but it has not been yet - so that can be ruled out too. *shrugs*

Comment: Okay, if AntiVirus is ruled out - then the problem apparently lies in the latest SwiftMailer version. You can either report the issue to their support team or you can try to debug it yourself. If you are not keen to debug it - I can only advice you to switch to PHPMailer. I am using it for the last 12-15 years and it works like a charm. With a small patch PHPMailer can even encrypt and sign emails. And adding attachments is as simple as `$message->AddAttachment($dir.'/'.$file)` You will not regret it.

Comment: Thanks IVO G, I appreciate it. I already added an "open issue" into the Swiftmailer section of Github, nothing yet. Either way, at this point I'll try PHPMailer to see if at least I can get traction with something, thanks again!

Comment: Well, I had no luck with Swiftmailer and I can't wait around for solutions - so I went with PHPMailer instead as you suggested IVO G!

Since there's some wierd issue with the combination of a Windows Server 2019, PHP 7.3 and the new Swiftmailer - I'm moving on! PHPMailer works like a charm!

Thanks a bunch and Take Care! :-)

Comment: You are welcome! PHPMailer rulez!!!